# Access sharepoint web service from separate HTML application

Tags: javascript, web-services

I want to access list items from a SharePoint 2010 site in a HTML application (not connected to the SharePoint site).

My approach is to use SharePoint web services by passing user credentials through JavaScript or JQuery.

I know I need to use `_vti_bin/lists.asmx` to access list items and  `_vti_bin/authentication.asmx` to authenticate, 
but some how I am not able to put things together and make it work.

Can I get some directions?

Good to know: My SharePoint site is not accessible to anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185006%28v=office.14%29.aspx) will allow you to use a more standard api to connect to SharePoint from off the server. There is also a version for C# if your "HTML" is a aspx site as well.

Comment: yes i know we can do with SharePoint Client Object Model,but my requirement is to use java script & my html application is not an aspx site,i cant use C#..

Comment: Did you go to the link? Also "There is also a version for C#" the link I gave you is for the JAVASCRIPT version of CSOM.